# How to compare text from two data frames in a wordcloud using R's quanteda package?

Tags: r, dataframe, quanteda

Suppose I have two data frames (`country_x` and `country_y` which contain similar columns). E.g.

```
text_country_x
hello
bye
```

and

```
text_country_y
see ya
great
```

Using `quanteda` and `quanteda.textplots` packages, I have created a word cloud:

```
corpus_country_x <- corpus(country_x_df$text_country_x)

country_x_token <- tokens(corpus_country_x, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)

country_x_token <- tokens_remove(country_x_token , stopwords("english"))

token_dfm_x <- dfm(country_x_token)

quanteda.textplots::textplot_wordcloud(token_dfm_x)
```

However, I want to create a wordcloud where half of it contains text from `text_country_x` and the other half contains text from `text_country_y`. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know there is the `comparison = TRUE` parameter but not sure how to make it work in practice: [https://quanteda.io/reference/textplot_wordcloud.html#:~:text=To%20produce%20word%20cloud%20plots,each%20document%20in%20the%20dfm.](https://quanteda.io/reference/textplot_wordcloud.html#:%7E:text=To%20produce%20word%20cloud%20plots,each%20document%20in%20the%20dfm.).

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

1. Form each corpus separately
2. Set a docvar for each corpus to differentiate the country. (Below, I use the document variable `set`)
3. Combine the corpus objects using `+`
4. Tokenise and form a dfm, then group the dfm using your `set` variable (country, in your example)
5. Plot the comparison wordcloud.

```r
library("quanteda")
#> Package version: 3.2.1
#> Unicode version: 14.0
#> ICU version: 70.1
#> Parallel computing: 10 of 10 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corpus_country_x <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, Party == "Democratic")
corpus_country_x$set <- "Dem"

corpus_country_y <- corpus_subset(data_corpus_inaugural, Party == "Republican")
corpus_country_y$set <- "Rep"

corp <- corpus_country_x + corpus_country_y

dfmat <- tokens(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(stopwords("en")) %>%
    dfm() %>%
    dfm_group(groups = set)

library("quanteda.textplots")
textplot_wordcloud(dfmat, max_words = 60, comparison = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>